Шаблон grid, расположить 12 блоков в одном родителе
grid-template:
        "a a b b b b b b b b " 110px
        "c c c c c c c c c c" 70px / 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;

Во втором ряде необходимо расположить 10 одинаковых блока, изображения.
Если каждому изображению присвоить grid-area: с; друг на друга закинет. А присваивать каждому изображению уникальный area. Как то накладно, все блоки в одном родителе...
По порядку, блок a - 1шт(изображение), c - 10 шт (изображения), b - простой div
В первом ряду, блок a должен занимать 20%, остальное блок 'b'
Во втором ряду необходимо расположить 10 изображений, так чтобы они равномерно заняли всю ширину.


.container { 
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  grid-template:
    "a a b b b b b b b b" 170px 
    "c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12" 70px;
}

.b { grid-area: b; }
.a { grid-area: a; }

.c:nth-child(3) {grid-area: c3}
.c:nth-child(4) {grid-area: c4}
.c:nth-child(5) {grid-area: c5}
.c:nth-child(6) {grid-area: c6}
.c:nth-child(7) {grid-area: c7}
.c:nth-child(8) {grid-area: c8}
.c:nth-child(9) {grid-area: c9}
.c:nth-child(9) {grid-area: c9}
.c:nth-child(11){grid-area: c11}
.c:nth-child(12){grid-area: c12}

.container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.container *:after {
  content:attr(class);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>




Возможно вам проще использовать вложенный грид.

https://grid.layoutit.com/?id=vC5NdUy

Одним гридом - у вас первые два блока c ограничены шириной a, они не будут резиновыми

Кто мне минусы ставит) У меня сейчас так и сделано, что второй ряд содержит один блок в котором 10 дочерних, хотел бы вынести их и сделать все в одном родителе. В качестве решения, каждому блоку с присвоить уникальный  area. Работать будет, возможно трудности с ширинами первого ряда возникнет, не критично

Правы, не работает так. Пытался через :nth-child каждому блоку c присвоить area. Вместо 2 блоков под блоком b размещает один...

Снова не прав, все замечательно работает. Добавил пример, да с шириной первого ряда интересно. Возможно есть у кого идеи? В css возможно присвоить area, как бы циклом? Чтобы не для каждого адресно не прописывать...?

Попробуйте использовать безымянные зоны (точку)

Знать бы что это, можно пример, не понимаю что значит 'точка' в безымянной зоне.

Десять раз перечитал когда этот вопрос появился, потом ещё раз пять, потом дождался комментариев и судя по всему никто ничего не понимает благодаря вашим формулировкам и что вы хотите добиться. Но, по крайней мере сейчас, когда появился код, который отрисовывает вашу хотелку, то, если я правильно понял вы хотите меньшими усилиями отрисовать подобное? Тогда как-то так:


.container { 
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  padding:10px;
  grid-template-rows: 170px 70px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}
.container *:after {
  content:attr(class);
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container > div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.b {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 1 / 11;
}
.a {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 3;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>



P.S. и, не знаю с какой целью у вас были изменены местоположения блоков .a и .b но если вы захотите их поменять местами в контейнере, то для корректного переразмещения достаточно будет поменять их grid-area.

Если разрешение экрана будет 500. Возможно сделать так, чтобы 2 блок был во всю ширину, а первый был с остальными. То есть 11 блоков в 4 ряда. Никак не выходит, придется пожалуй отдельный код на все делать. 2-3 изменениями свойств не выйдет?

@Роман естественно можно. Через @media запрос вам достаточно будет поменять grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr); у блока .b {grid-area: 1/1/1/12;} а у блока .a убрать grid-area или возможно через сброс .a {grid-area: inherit;} если что будет ниже размером 320px например.  В общем учитесь и экспериментируйте.)
